# JSON Bucket for Wordpress with Authentication

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Is there a WordPress plugin that can store JSON in the database and retrieve it?

I have a WordPress site which I want to use to host a rather simple, mostly client-side app, but which needs authentication and a place to store its data. Some of the data is for each user and some of it will be accessed by all users.

It doesn't even necessarily need to be a WordPress plugin -- Just a simple PHP script would work too, if it would tie into the WordPress authentication somehow.

I would use NodeJS, but the rest of our websites use WordPress, and this will let me use the same theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [WordPress REST API](http://wp-api.org) and [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). The plugin that couples them together is [ACF to WP API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-wp-api/), however I had to modify it to allow saving changes back to WordPress, which wasn't hard.